# Has Tony Stark ever "gone commando" in the Iron Man suit?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

Tony Stark always seems to wears clothes in the Iron Man suit in the movies.

Has he ever gone commando, i.e. worn just his 'birthday suit' in the Iron Man suit?

Comment: [Badoom-tish](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/dd/f8/23/ddf8239bfa5f5b28a6009f962014d158.jpg)

Comment: Not conclusive, but in the comics, there was a scene where he and another character were fighting, but to appease local religious sensibilities they had to stop, strip down, and finish the fight completely naked.  There was a panel of them (legs down) walking away from two suits, and there was no additional under-clothing around Iron Man's.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my strong suit. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: @KyloRen - Iron is Tony's strong suit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. In [Marvel Adventures: Iron Man #8](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Adventures:_Iron_Man_Vol_1?file=Marvel_Adventures_Iron_Man_Vol_1_8.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Is there any *reason* he's naked in this part of the comic, or is it totally gratuitous?

Comment: @apnorton - No real explanation is offered.